# How Does Disabling Cors Plugins Work

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I am trying to work around some CORS issues im currently facing, I would to know how CORS disabling plugins work so i can use that technique to solve my problem.

Comment: What is your server, Is it nodejs express?

Comment: What do you mean by plugins? have some examples??

Comment: Google Chrome Disable CORS plugin

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins but most of them works that way:

It allows to you request any site with ajax from any source. It simply adds to response 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header.

What is more `disable cors` uses that technique:

It rewrites the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to have the value of Origin header. In other words, to the browser, it appears that the server has whitelisted exactly the site you're on.

They said:

> This is better than Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (the approach taken
>   by CORS Toggle) because Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is not allowed
>   on requests that use credentials (the common case for APIs).